# How to disable time synchronization on hyper V

Tags: hyper-v, time-synchronization

I have test machine on hyper v (only for test purposes so I can do with it whatever I want to), it is ws 2008 r2 x64. I need to change date to 2008 year in order to test some scenarios with expired certificates. Is there a possibility to disable hyper v time synchronization. I found some hyper v services however I cannot stop them (there is no such an option).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Hyper-V Manager, open the VM's Settings, Integration Services Tab, Uncheck Time Synchronization.